# finding next empty row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This might be easy for many but I need to solve an issue which is following;

I have the following formula which finds the empty row after D4.

```
 =MATCH(TRUE;D4:D1048576="";0)+3
```

After this I want to be able to find the empty row from another defined cell, say D10.

How can I do this?

Comment: Switch `D4` with `D10`. Like this `=MATCH(TRUE;D10:D1048576="";0)+3`

Comment: it does not work, i tried before

Comment: Try this `=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(D10:D1048576),0),0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as an array formula - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
=MIN(IF(D4:D100="",ROW(D4:D100)))
```

It works from `D4` to `D100`, providing the first empty value.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to use same formula to match next cell then use

For blanks after D4

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(D4:D1048576),0),0)
```

For blanks after D10

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(D10:D1048576),0),0)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this does not find the one after D10. It finds how many cells there are between the D10 and next empty cell. Lets say my empty cell is at D19. Formula gives me 9 and not D19

Comment: @SoruSoravic So you want the answer to be 19 instead of 9 ? (the starting row would first row and not the 10th row)

Comment: yes but the problem is, cell 19 is not the first empty row. because i use the formule already for d4 to d10 ( d9 is blank so first blank is found). Now i need to find from d10 to d19 and want to return 19. Because if i use it from D1, it ll return me the first blank which is d9

Comment: =MATCH(TRUE;D4:D1048576="";0)+3  this formula returns me 9 which is an empty row in D9 so it works. When i try to find another empty row from D10 the formula does not work but i want it to return 19 because next empty cell is D19

Answer (score 0):

To find the `A1`<sup>th</sup> blank cell, you can use the following formula:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(D:D)/--ISBLANK(D:D),A1)
```

### How it works

`AGGREGATE(15,6,..)` is like `SMALL(..)`, but skips any error values.

`ROW(..)` provides the row number of the cell provided

`ISBLANK(..)` is `TRUE` for blank cells or `FALSE` for non-blank cells

`--` converts `TRUE` to `1` and `FALSE` to `0`.  This means that `ROW(D:D)/--ISBLANK(D:D)` will be either the Row Number (for blank cells) or a `#Div0!` error (which `AGGREGATE` will skip)

This produces a list of row numbers for all the blank cells, and you then use [the `AGGREGATE` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/aggregate-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df) to get the *k*<sup>th</sup> item in that list.

### Taking it a step further

So, you want the 1st item larger than a specific row.  We change the last argument in `AGGREGATE` to `1`, and swap change our "Error out" code from `ISBLANK(D:D)` to `AND(ISBLANK(D:D), ROW(D:D)>A1)`, to get the first blank row after the row number stored in `A1`:

```
=AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(D:D)/--AND(ISBLANK(D:D), ROW(D:D)>A1), 1)
```